# Remove null attributes from request body Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I'm new to spring boot and was referring to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) article. It asks to add `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation to remove null attributes from **response body**, however I'm interested in removing null attributes from **request body**.
Please suggest how can I achieve that.

The request body is:

```
{
    "userUuid": "2u9k2ld8f-ghj47dhj",
    "suggestion": null
}
```

and the request DTO class is:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserRequestDTO implements Serializable {
    private String userUuid;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private String suggestion;
}
```

Clearly it is not working for me. When I stringify and print the request body, it includes `suggestion` attr which is `null`.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You want to remove `null` values and replace it with what?

Comment: Have you achivied successfully on response body? About request why remove from request? What do you want to put in your DTO when you got null attr? Because there is no way to ignore an attribute from object Java...

Comment: @JoãoDias I do simply want to drop that attr.

Comment: @DilermandoLima Yes, I achivied it on response body. I need to generate the checksum of the payload excluding the null attrs. I do not want to replace null attr rather remove it.
To generate the signature I will to doing `.toString()` on the request body.

Comment: Request is something tha tis being send to you, trying to solve that on the server isn't going to work. So unless you are sending things yourself this won't work. Anyway please add the code you use for testing this? How are you *stringify*ing this?

Answer (score 1):

Well... Do not use `toString()` use Jackson ObjectMapper. So like:

```
var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
var dto = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, UserRequestDTO.class);
var strNoNullFields = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto);
```

That way the annotation is working.

Anyway this is not something very optimal. You might want to re-think your design how to calculate checksum (your question smells a bit like [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/)).

Answer (score -2):

> I need to generate the checksum of the payload excluding the null attrs. I do not want to replace null attr rather remove it. To generate the signature I will to doing .toString() on the request body

I think you are looking for a request has dynamic attributes.

Try use a `HashMap<String,Object>` on parameters.

Other simple way is overriding  `toString()` from DTO and ignore null attrs.

Suggestions:  Besides using this only for logging I think both is bad practice could be better create a method `generateSignature()` handles all rules of this.

Comment: toString won't convert to json (Jackson does that). Using a map to retrieve things doesn't sovle it either as there can be `null` values as well.